# giflib usage for editing animated gif

Tags: c, gif

The aim is for a given GIF file including several images inside to extract those image pixels, edit (change them) and put them back to the GIF file.
Trying to do it using giflib.

The language used is C.

I have successfully read the Gif file and have an access to the pixels of image using the following code:

```
GifFileType *gifFile = DGifOpenFileName(filename);
DGifSlurp(gifFile);
```

But as it is said in the [Documentation](http://wwwcdf.pd.infn.it/libgif/gif_lib.html):
About the DGifSlurp function:

> When you have modified the image to taste, write it out with
>   EGifSpew().

However using that function results in:
GIF-LIB error: Given file was not opened for write.

In the following code:

```
GifFileType *gifFile = DGifOpenFileName(filename);
DGifSlurp(gifFile);
EGifSpew(gifFile);
```

Do you know how to save the edited gif image?

Answer (score 0):

Your doc is outdated. You should take a look here: http://giflib.sourceforge.net/gif_lib.html#idp26995312

You can write to a GIF file through a function hook. Initialize with

GifFileType *EGifOpen(void *userPtr, OutputFunc writeFunc, int *ErrorCode)
and see the library header file for the type of OutputFunc.

Moreover the function EGifSpew() takes a fd in second argument to a gifFile.

Hope it helped.